# When adding FarseerPhysics to XNA project Xml serialization doesnt work

Tags: c#, xml, xna, box2d, physics

When I add Physics to my game, XmlSeralizer can not deserialize the GameplayScreen.xml file and that really bugs me out. But as soon as I remove the physics from everywhere everything is OK again. I have an Entity class to which I add a Body and a base GameScreen class to which I add World class (basically Physics World) and I suppose XmlSerializer doesn't like physics for some strange reason.

I myself tried searching for some attributes that, may be, do not allow for xml serialization, but found nothing, I'm desperate.

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: You probably have an error in the xml.  You should run the xml through a syntax check.  You can do this in VS.  From project menu : Add New Item : XML file.  Then paste your xml into the view making sure you have the xml identification line at beginning of file.  The check for errors in error window.

Comment: nope, the thing is that even without writing anything new to xml file it doesn't work and there is nothing related to the physics in my xml files

Comment: A I said "The XML original XML contains errors".  Check for errors.

Comment: it doesnt have any errors, it worked perfectly fine before

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the solution. The key is to put [XmlIgnore] on all the Farseer physics objects and stuff.